# how to migrate sql update query in teradata?

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I would like to migrate the below query in teradata. I'm updating some rows in my table and have written this query in sql. Now, I want to migrate below script in teradata. I heard that we need to use volatile table to select the data and then update. Is it mandatory that I need to create a volatile table first and then update?

```
UPDATE gam 
    SET gam.DeviceActiveInSIGMA = 1,
    gam.DeviceInSIGMA =1,
    gam.AccountServiceInSIGMA =1,
    gam.AccountInSIGMA =1,
    gam.PKG_TYPE = 'VOICE',
    gam.MACType = 'Voice'
  FROM Staging.AllAccountDevices gam
  WITH (INDEX (ix_MAC_UniqueID))
  INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_SIGMA_VOIP_EQUIPMENT dvc
     ON gam.MACAddr = dvc.MTA_MAC
  INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_SIGMA_SUB sac
  ON dvc.SUB_ID = sac.SUB_ID
  AND gam.AccountNumber = sac.Account_Number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN HSIRECON.DBO.NEXTGEN_ACTIVE_SPAS nas 
  ON SUBSTRING(gam.AccountNumber,1,6) = nas.ACCOUNT_START

  WHERE nas.ACCOUNT_START is NULL
  AND gam.DeviceActiveInSIGMA = 0
  AND dvc.STATUS IN ('active','change_in_progress')
```

Comment: Are you trying to migrate the above query _from_ some other database _into_ Teradata?  If so, for which other database was this query written?

Comment: This query is written for oracle db. Now migrating into teradata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a Volatile Table, but a Derived Table, because Teradata doesn't support Outer Joins in Updates.

Similar to this:

```
UPDATE gam
FROM Staging.AllAccountDevices  AS gam,
 (
   SELECT *  FROM Staging.AllAccountDevices gam
   INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_SIGMA_VOIP_EQUIPMENT dvc
      ON gam.MACAddr = dvc.MTA_MAC
   INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_SIGMA_SUB sac
   ON dvc.SUB_ID = sac.SUB_ID
   AND gam.AccountNumber = sac.Account_Number
   LEFT OUTER JOIN HSIRECON.DBO.NEXTGEN_ACTIVE_SPAS nas 
   ON Substr(gam.AccountNumber,1,6) = nas.ACCOUNT_START
   WHERE nas.ACCOUNT_START IS NULL
   AND gam.DeviceActiveInSIGMA = 0
   AND dvc.STATUS IN ('active','change_in_progress')
 ) AS dt

SET DeviceActiveInSIGMA = 1,
    DeviceInSIGMA =1,
    AccountServiceInSIGMA =1,
    AccountInSIGMA =1,
    PKG_TYPE = 'VOICE',
    MACType = 'Voice'
WHERE gam.pk = dt.pk -- must be the Primary Key columns(s) of Staging.AllAccountDevices
  AND gam.DeviceActiveInSIGMA = 0
```

Btw, the original query was written for SQL Server, not Oracle.